# Passing context in *http.request in middleware gives an error

Tags: http, go, middleware

I am trying to pass some data to handler function through a chi middleware like this:

```golang
ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), int32(0), company)
next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
return
```

But the next.ServeHTTP() throws this error:

```
interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not *chi.Context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

context.Background() gives a non-nil context and that's why the `interface{} is nil` error is arising. You need to use update the context embedded in request itself. Try this:

```golang
ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), int32(0), company)
next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
return
```